# Is it safe to publish file paths on a server publicly?

Tags: data-leakage

If I'm sharing information on a setup script for example, and I share it in a pastebin or a Github Gist, are there any security issues if the posted information includes absolute file paths to real resources on my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server is otherwise secure then its simply not recommended to do so, but poses no immediate threats.

However, if your hosting a web server there are extra risks involved such as SSI (server side includes) which will allow individuals to access those paths. You may want to double check your server user permissions and vulnerabilities first.

Its rarely necessary to use absolute paths and is just an extra risk. Your just laying our breadcrumbs for someone with malicious intent ;)

Comment: Security aside, absolute paths are usually a bad idea from an application maintenance perspective.

Comment: that too :)
i think i forgot to mention simply do to this question being security related

Comment: Well the main reason why I have to use absolute paths is because this is for a systemd service file, which I can't seem to get to parse variables when specifying paths. Trust me, i prefer to hide and abstract as much as possible but for whatever reason systemd's architects decided not to allow that.

Comment: Hmmm... in that case found this which i hope can help you, it might be in java but the answer seems relevant/possible: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199081/writing-a-systemd-unit-file-with-a-environment-set-executable-path

Comment: Thanks, I think I may have figured a way to hide this information, though it would still require one absolute path. Welcome to StackExchange, BTW!

Comment: Thank you! im trying to improve my answering of questions and hopefully i can be useful for the community :)